# Change ContentType - SharePoint Workflow in VS2008

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I need to change the ContentType in my Sharepoint workflow. If I set the following will this change it? If not how. If I am presently using ContentType 1 for a List and want to switch to using ContentType 2 what code do I need in order to make this happen?

```
SPListItem currentItem = workflowProperties.Item;
SPContentType myCType = workflowProperties.List.ContentTypes["ContentType 2"];

        currentItem["ContentTypeId"] = myCType.Id;
        currentItem.Update();
```

I'm thinking this will work but not sure.

Thanks,
JJ

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me. I would call `currentItem.SystemUpdate()` in the end, since this leaves the 'modified date' and 'modified by' fields untouched. If you simply call `Update`, it will show the item as modified by "Sharepoint\system"